# Print ncvTest to csv file

Tags: r, csv

In R i run a `ncvTest` for heteroscedasticity. But i can't seem to print the result into a csv file. This is what i have done,

`ncvt<-ncvTest(pol_reg)
outss<-file(paste0("hetero_test.csv"))
write.csv(ncvt,outss)`

I get the following error message,

`Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors) : 
  cannot coerce class ""chisqTest"" to a data.frame`

What am I suppose to do in order to save the result into a csv file. The result of `ncvt` looks as follows,

`Non-constant Variance Score Test 
Variance formula: ~ fitted.values 
Chisquare = 75514.06    Df = 1     p = 0`

Comment: Try `writeLines()` and saving it as `.txt`.

Comment: The `ncvt` result you get from calling `ncvTest` isn't a data frame.  So we need to find a way to get a data frame from your result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pull out components of your ncvt list and make a dataframe out of it to write to a csv file:

```
ncvt<-ncvTest(pol_reg)
ds_ncvt <- data.frame(ncvt$formula.name, ncvt$ChiSquare, ncvt$Df, ncvt$p, ncvt$test)
outss<-file(paste0("hetero_test.csv"))
write.csv(ds_ncvt,outss)
```

Comment: Bingo!  I wasn't sure what the type of `ncvt` because I didn't have an R console in front of me.  Your response should work great.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, the following also works

`ncvt<-ncvTest(pol_reg)
ds_ncvt <- as.matrix(ncvt)
outss<-file(paste0("hetero_test.csv"))
write.csv(ds_ncvt,outss)`